# ChromeDriver FlashPolicyHelper does not work remotely

Tags: selenium-webdriver, chromedriver, flash-selenium

We're using the

```
  new FlashPolicyHelper(driver).addSite("https://your.site")
```

In order to bypass the getFlash prompt when trying to navigate to our websites that use Flash.

However this does not seem to work when executed remotely.

Current Implementation

Calling the FlashPolicyHelper Class

```
if(browser.driver instanceof ChromeDriver)
    {
      new FlashPolicyHelper((ChromeDriver) browser.driver).addSite(odysseyURL)
    }
    browser


public class FlashPolicyHelper
{
private final ChromeDriver driver;

public FlashPolicyHelper(ChromeDriver driver) {
    this.driver = driver;
}

public FlashPolicyHelper addSite(String site) {
    try {
        this.driver.get("chrome://settings/content/siteDetails?site=" + site);
... rest of code for FlashPolicyHelper found here...
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52185371/allow-flash-content-in-chrome-69-running-via-chromedriver

Comment: Cross posted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59635105/chromedriver-flashpolicyhelper-does-not-work-remotely

Comment: Is the Bamboo agent running the driver in headless mode? I think the FlashPolicyHelper code from this question might not work headless: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52185371/allow-flash-content-in-chrome-69-running-via-chromedriver

Comment: @NielsvanReijmersdal The bamboo agent sends the request to our Selenium Grid hub. Which in turn farms it out to the various nodes. They are not headless.
The Bamboo agent simply collects all of our test results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized I needed to instantiate a Remote Web Driver in order to obtain functionality remotely. Solved.

```
if(browser.driver instanceof RemoteWebDriver)
{
  new FlashPolicyHelper((RemoteWebDriver) browser.driver).addSite(odysseyURL)
}
browser


public class FlashPolicyHelper
{
private final RemoteWebDriver driver;

public FlashPolicyHelper(RemoteWebDriver driver) {
this.driver = driver;
}

public FlashPolicyHelper addSite(String site) {
try {
    this.driver.get("chrome://settings/content/siteDetails?site=" + site);
... rest of code for FlashPolicyHelper found here...
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52185371/allow-flash-content-in-chrome-69-running-via-chromedriver

Comment: For the sake of anyone else who runs into this kind of problem, could you please edit your answer to include the code that solved your problem?

Comment: Can do @KatePaulk